# Is it better to use multiple databases when you are managing independent sets of things in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

If, as an example, you have a blogging website done with MongoDB to store data

Is it better to have a database per blogger? given that their blogs and comments are completely independent from other bloggers.   Or just lump everything together? or it doesn't make too much difference?

I'm imagining the same web app (not independent webs/urls per blogger) is used by all bloggers.  So when someone logs in / accesses the blog the code would find the right database to use and haul data out it.

Does this have any downsides?  is this normal for handling these kinds of things?

Comment: I think you'll have issues with space if you generate multiple dbs (hundreds?). This is because the memory allocated by MongoDB is done in chunks (minimum of 64 MB initially). Also, I don't see any possible benefits of this - it doesn't add functionality, it doesn't add speed, it doesn't take less space...

Comment: wouldn't it help some queries?  I'm not sure I choose the best example, but if you needed to query a collection for all items related to a blogger,  in a single db scenario, you simply just have to fetch all items?

Comment: Have collection per blogger in such case. If you have index on blogger name, even storing all in one collection it will be almost as quick as separate collections or databases.

Comment: ahhhh, very good point.

Comment: DO NOT HAVE A COLLECTION PER BLOGGER, you will regret it.

Comment: @sashkello How will he have issue with space if memory allocation is 64mb by default? I am confused how memory allocation effects disk space...

Answer (score 4):

I am making plenty of assumptions about your needs.  But, generally, there are 3 paths to multi-tenant apps in MongoDB:

Single collection per customer; never, ever do this.

Single database per customer.  Good.  You will trade off free space if your product is on the freemium model.  Either way, you will want to run with "smallfiles" option.  As stated, you will build the routing system for your environment.  Thus, you will want to connect to the proper database for the proper customer.

customer_id key per document + path slug.  Good.  The trade off here is recovery of free space.  Traditionally, MongoDB does not recover space used by deleted documents.  Thus customers creating and deleting blog posts would create unused space.  By using 'usePowerOf2Sizes' collections, you will recover disk space of deleted documents.  However, 'usePowerOf2Sizes' creates bloated padding space.

To get over the disk space padding, take a look at the compression used here: http://blog.appsignal.com/blog/2013/07/30/taming-mongodb-disk-usage.html

Recap, I would recommend using customer_id plus the compression.  It gives you the best of both worlds.

Comment: +1, like the cust_id+path slug approach considering there won't be much deletions

Comment: Diusk reuse WILL happen regardless, the reason why fragmentation occurs is you have documents which do not fit into their previous space, powerof2sizes allocation should only be used on high write scenarios since in any other scenario it will actually create unperformant operation of the database. A good schema is all that is needed 90% of the time to tame disk space usage

Comment: Whats the reasoning for not having a collection per customer?

Comment: @KeithNicholas Allocation, too many times someone has come onto the user group with space exceeding 50-100x due to the way MongoDB will allocate 2GB extents for collections at a certain point. Using separate collections caused that, not only that but there is no performance gain to that setup, none. The only performance gain type setup could be database separation atm

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the comments under the original question, there's really no performance benefit to splitting up your MongoDB store into separate databases per blogger, due to the overhead of having each database and minimum storage.

On the flipside: You *are* going to make some cross-user analysis more difficult for yourself. As a very simple example, based on your blogging example: Imagine you want to look at average post count per user. This is pretty simple if your users (and posts) are in the same database (typically in the same collections), and you can likely use the aggregation framework for this task. This task will not be so straightforward with an unbounded number of databases, where you'll need to first enumerate all databases, then perform your aggregations/averaging once per database. This could end up being a slower operation than within a single-database architecture.

Having said all that: You *still* might have some reason to split data across databases. Maybe you have to separate data due to legal reasons, or to ensure customers that their sensitive data won't be commingled with other companies' data. Maybe your customer needs full read/write access to their database, and so you use per-database configuration as a security boundary. I'm sure there are other reasons as well...

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly normal to allocate 100's of databases if that is all you will see.

Database separation can have many benefits. They can be sharded independantly, since sharding occurs on database level. Databases also have the upside of being completely isolated instances (including locks) of the data within them (good example: space allocation occurs on database level).

This means they can be moved around the network as users data is accessed more and since a single users data might not be that big it would be easier than moving all of your users data to a more powerful node.

However, you must consider the problematic sides in the application of managing the connections to each database. There will be over head on it and you will need to have far more complex coding than what is considered standard.

Considering space, you will not see a drastic usage of space. The most problematic part of using separate databases is the journal allocation. Every collection you use in separate databases will also, of course, pre-allocate itself but this is actually considered one of the upsides to using database separation (movement of databases between nodes, isolation).

So the space problem is really only a problem if your scenario makes it one.

> is this normal for handling these kinds of things?

For a normal blogger site, no, and I do not know enough about the complexities of your scenario to say any different. Normal operation would be to lump everything together, since you could see into the region of 1,000's maybe 1,000,000's of users and database separation just won't scale over that very well.

Comment: I'm not actually doing a blogging site,  just trying to use it as a well understood example.  The essence of my question is really about the tradeoffs of partitioning data by using databases vs querying

Comment: @KeithNicholas There is no generic answer, it is very scenario dependant as to what you do