# MongoDB: throw everything into the same database?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database

Currently, all my collections are maintained in a single database.

I'm a little confused on when I should separate my collections into multiple databases, as some of the collections aren't necessarily related.

**multiple databases**:

- can refine security permissions
- separation of concerns

**single database**

- easy

There are a set of tables I access all the time, and a set of tables I access about once a month. It makes some sense to open a persistent connection to a database containing my always-used tables, and open a connection to a database containing the sparsely-used tables when needed.

But is there any *performance* difference to having all my data in the same database? Is there any general rule-of-thumb to when to use multiple databases (other than production, development, etc.)

Comment: The time is when your database would benefit from the database isolation, this case is so rare that I can probably bet £20 you don't have this case

Comment: @Sammaye answers the question. Thanks man

Comment: Added note, since I realised my comment was very vague, the main reason normally for people branching out is because of the locks, but the locks is such a rare problem, so many blame them yet normally the problem is IO/CPU/RAM bottleneck instead. But yeah, other benefits are of course isolation of allocation and sharding but that is a rare case that it helps

Answer (score 1):

Check here for a similar question with some useful, more in-depth answers: [Is it better to use multiple databases when you are managing independent sets of things in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222630/is-it-better-to-use-multiple-databases-when-you-are-managing-independent-sets-of)