# Mongo DB - is 1 DB per client really recommended for multi-tenant SAAS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

this article suggests that using MongoDB for a SAAS application that you should use one DB for each client - can this be right?  http://docs.mongohq.com/use-cases/marketing-platforms.html (see bottom of page)

If so are there any occasions when it would still pay to put all clients into one DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked a similar question

[Is it better to use multiple databases when you are managing independent sets of things in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222630/is-it-better-to-use-multiple-databases-when-you-are-managing-independent-sets-of)

The conclusion seems to be its not really very efficient to have multiple databases.  But its still a valid way of doing things.

A more important consideration is if you want to do queries across customers for whatever reason, then your job gets a lot more difficult if they are in separate databases.

Comment: Thanks - it didn't seem quite right to me..

Comment: Is this different from sharding? I've wondered this very same thing. Sometime ago I had decided sharding was acceptable because every query would probably have the client id. I was thinking this would improve performance for each client. Lately, I am slower to turn to sharding.